# Angular Library Dependency Injection issues

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, shared-libraries

I'm having some dificulties understanding exactly what I'm doing wrong but I'm trying to have an angular lib with a couple of services which need DI and then use these services in an app.

As of right now I used a fresh ng app and fresh ng lib, they are not in the same root project. Used all the oficial commands:

```
ng new app
ng new libs --no-create-application
cd libs
ng g library test
```

From this initial test which generated a `libs-lib.service.ts` I duplicated it and created a new one `libs-lib2.service.ts` contents:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LibsLib2Service {

  constructor() { }
}
```

then I modified the original to require the new one:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LibsLibService {

  constructor(private lib: LibsLib2Service) { }
}
```

After this I ran:

```
ng build libs-lib
cd dist/libs
npm link

cd ../../../app/
npm link libs-lib
```

then in this app I added a testing service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TestingService {

  constructor(private api: LibsLib2Service) { }
}
```

This works just fine... BUT if I use the original instead ( which is using DI ) like this:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TestingService {

  constructor(private api: LibsLibService) { }
}
```

then I'm getting the following error:
`ERROR Error: NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with 'EnvironmentInjector#runInContext'. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0203`

I've also made multiple attempts at adding services as providers to a module and importing them but with really no success at all.
What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Interestingly, I made the same example but within the same workspace and it seemed to work just fine. I seems like something in the npm link. I'll keep checking and testing.

Answer (score 0):

"Issue found" or rather... source of issue found, reason is still beyond my capabilities to understand.

Anyway, solution is just don't use npm link...
I did the exact same thing but instead of npm link I used  yalc (https://www.npmjs.com/package/yalc) and it worked like a charm in less then 2 minutes.